# Similar triangles in Ptolemy and inversion

Tags: geometry

In this video at 30:56 seconds an equation is given.

https://youtu.be/bJOuzqu3MUQ?t=1856

How could that equation achieved?
So, are those triangles similar?

[image]

Comment: Since it's inversion, $r^2 = OA\cdot OA_1= OB\cdot OB_1$.

Comment: Thank you, i wonder whether they are similar and confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of inversion, the points $A_1$ and $B_2$ verify
$$r^2=OA\cdot OA_1=OB\cdot OB_1$$
This implies that
$$\frac{OA}{OB}=\frac{OB_1}{OA_1}$$
Since the angle
$$\angle AOB=\angle B_1OA_1$$
This indeed implies that the triangles $\triangle AOB$ and $\triangle B_1OA_1$ are similar!